Erreur (Xcode): Unable to read the input file as a list of properties
Problem with the simulator: XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.
Hi guys,
I tried to launch the simulator to see the progress of the application.
At first the simulator worked well and I could see the progress but right now, I don't know why, the simulator no longer works and this message appears:
"Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           25,1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): unable to read input file as a property list: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 2.)
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max."
I've done some research, looked at the documentation on property lists and everything but I haven't found the solution yet. So I don't see the progress of the application.
Have you ever had this problem?
Can you help me with this?
Thank you in advance
